# logstash -> elasticsearch: how can I remove all data before output new data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

logstash get multiple events once a week, then it forward these events to elasticsearch,

How can I configure logstash to let it tell elasticsearch to delete old events?

EDIT 2018-03-28:

### Input:

```
{host:"host1", type:"packages", records: [{name:"pkg1", ver: "1"}, {name: "pkg2", ver: "2"},...]
{host:"host1", type:"mounts", records: [{path:"path1", dev: "dev1"}, {path:"path2", dev: "dev2"},...]
{host:"host1", type:"???", records: [{???}, {???},...]
...
{host:"host2", type:"packages, records: [{name:"pkg1", version: "1"}, {name: "pkg2", ver: "2"},...]
{host:"host2", type: "mounts", records: [{path:"path1", dev: "dev1"}, {path:"path2", dev: "dev2"},...]
{host:"host2", type:"???", records: [{???}, {???},...]
```

That is various events for each host. Every event consists of an array of ***undeterminable*** schema.

To be able to search field in array precisely, I must split the array into multiple elasticsearch documents.

(I know there are ways to not split yet be able to search inside array. That is another story: [Nested Object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html). In my case, the inner object is not fixed schema, so I can NOT provide every inner field definition beforehand)

### Output:

```
{host: "host1", type:"packages", record: {name: "pkg1", ver: "1"}}
{host: "host1", type:"packages", record: {name: "pkg2", ver: "2"}}
{host: "host1", type:"mounts", record: {path: "path1", dev: "dev1"}}
{host: "host1", type:"???", record: {???}
{host: "host1", type:"???", record: {???}
{host: "host1", type:"mounts", record: {path: "path2", dev: "dev2"}}
{host: "host2", type:"packages", record: {name: "pkg1", ver: "1"}}
{host: "host2", type:"packages", record: {name: "pkg2", ver: "2"}}
{host: "host2", type:"mounts", record: {path: "path1", dev: "dev1"}}
{host: "host2", type:"mounts", record: {path: "path2", dev: "dev2"}}
{host: "host2", type:"???", record: {???}
{host: "host2", type:"???", record: {???}
...
```

### logstash.conf:

```
input { ... }

filter {
    split {
      # split array and save them into new multiple events
      field => "records"
    }
    mutate {
      rename => { "records" => "record" }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["ELASTIC_IP:PORT"]
    index => "packages-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

-

### The problem is: Elasticsearch will be filled with more and more old events for each host each type.

So I want to remove old data for a host once I get new data for it.

### Note of some failed tries:

- [Overwrite existing document by specify document id in the logstash.conf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id)

Because the output is multiple documents, not a single document, sometimes more, sometime less, so it is not a simple update. It must be a remove all & add.

I know there are ways to not split yet be able to search inside array. That is another story: [Nested Object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html). In my case, the inner object is not fixed schema, so I can NOT provide every inner field definition beforehand

Comment: It depends on your organisation and since you've given few details, I can only give a vague answer: Use per-day or per-week indices in elasticsearch, then use [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/about-features.html) to delete the indices.

Comment: Or you could use the ES input (with the schedule setting) to retrieve the ids of the events to delete, then use the ES output to delete them (action: delete)

Comment: @baudsp thank you! your idea is interesting and useful. I have updated the question to add detail description.

Comment: @baudsp I am trying to use two elasticsearch output, one for delete index, another for add index. I do not know if them will be executed in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'v confirmed it can be done by ruby filter to delete old index .

```
input { ... }

filter {
  split {
    # split array and save them into new multiple events
    field => "records"
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { "records" => "record" }
  }

  ruby {
    init => "
       require 'net/http'
       require 'uri'
     "
    code => "
      uri = URI.parse('http://docker.for.mac.localhost:19200/inventory-' + event.get('type') + '@' + event.get('host'))
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      req = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri)
      req.basic_auth 'elastic', 'changeme'
      res = http.request(req)
    "
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["ELASTIC_IP:PORT"]
    index => "inventory-%{type}@%{host}"
  }
}
```

The important thing is specifying index for each combo of host&type so can be located easily when delete.

```
index => "inventory-%{type}@%{host}"
```